# Remove y-axis label from plot of an xts object

Tags: r, plot, xts

Here is the code generating a plot of an xts object:

```
require("quantmod")
getSymbols("SPY")
plot(Cl(SPY))
```

Which yields the following plot:

[image: graph]

Can you remove the y-axis values (the prices) from a plot of an xts object?

*Hint*: *passing* `yaxt='n'` *doesn't work*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the y-axis is easy, but it also removes the x-axis.  A couple options:

1) Easy -- use `plot.zoo`:

```
plot.zoo(Cl(SPY), yaxt="n", ylab="")
```

2) Harder-ish -- take pieces from `plot.xts`:

```
plot(Cl(SPY), axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=xy.coords(.index(SPY), SPY[, 1])$x[axTicksByTime(SPY)],
  label=names(axTicksByTime(SPY)), mgp = c(3, 2, 0))
```

3) Customize-ish -- modify `plot.xts` so `axes=` accepts a vector of axes to plot and/or `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

Comment: I like the easy solution best. Taking advantage of the zoo heritage. Thanks.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't use `plot.xts` too much.  `plot.zoo` has better functionality and it "just works" with xts objects.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Joshua's answer, to modify plot.xts(), all you need to do is alter the following section:

```
    if (axes) {
      if (minor.ticks) 
        axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB")
      axis(1, at = xycoords$x[ep], labels = names(ep), las = 1,lwd = 1, mgp = c(3, 2, 0))
    #This is the line to change:
    if (plotYaxis) axis(2)
    }
```

and obviously you add the parameter plotYaxis=TRUE to the function definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try specifying that the x and y as labels are empty, or contain no values/characters. Try using the term `xlab=""` in your plot command:
e.g. `plot(beers,ranking,xlab="",ylab="")`

By not including anything between the quotation marks, R doesn't plot anything.
Using this command, you can also specific the labels, so to make the label for the x axis 
'beer', use the term `xlab="beer"`.