# Plotting without x-axis not working

Tags: r, plot, xts

According to R's documentation and to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154397/6143363), adding clause `xaxt='n'` to `plot` function would remove the x-axis. But it is not working. **How can I remove the x-axis?** Note the data of the reproducible example is purposely large as otherwise the issue may not become apparent.

```
library(xts)

#Data
XTS2 <- structure(c(0.219372625180095, 0.219621309002056, 0.219672138096205, 0.219802192670588, 0.219864845456527, 0.219903875450378, 0.219878284684927, 0.219864700919602, 0.21985651328177, 0.219857825136631, 0.219884473722915, 0.219898694923239, 0.219885043080517, 0.219854528884288, 0.219891391116462, 
0.220009076372192, 0.220043450189938, 0.219875677981711, 0.219721321036969, 0.219758828022141, 0.219849042254386, 0.219879876725454, 0.219878646418273, 0.219894602486828, 0.219811609428382, 0.219793531899719, 0.219797131429743, 0.219855825952923, 0.219875561367165, 0.219858651084074, 0.219864158100624, 0.21986763110722, 0.219910853386158, 0.219814296888465, 0.219859611637469, 0.219918996841639, 0.219963561983058, 0.219994304642825, 0.220029191160333, 0.219758957034546, 0.219687680441127, 0.219633056927772, 0.219598040619723, 0.21934030011892, 0.219394314552813, 0.219578706291011, 0.219814709531839, 0.219684116969818, 0.219784045583737, 0.219751237724798, 0.219833014585797, 0.219807141408044, 0.219753066207534, 0.219718012325876, 0.21973771018932, 0.219803162803865, 0.219733737959443, 0.219688542058595, 0.219689360991042, 0.219818376281643, 0.21984708712555, 0.219820116196723, 0.219846725602203, 
0.219669833445315, 0.219861667333268, 0.219976424596682, 0.219970605220939, 0.220022350371598, 0.220091127852274, 0.220098017537939, 0.219793881178817, 0.219146686479004, 0.219270493990701, 0.219446599806344, 0.219356112506615, 0.21907529149545, 0.218978996562748, 0.219304317202003, 0.219326175023805, 0.219350894629431, 0.219316608166634, 0.219413886418147, 0.219052756629217, 0.219057431850469, 0.218926977685616, 0.218970132003055, 0.219061600571713, 0.219053251218667, 0.219017407867393, 0.218987520940269, 0.2190060296344, 0.21902931390176, 0.219102079717272, 0.219136627753565, 0.219233819022479, 0.219228483314638, 0.219204780731664, 0.219214972196354, 0.219340375121465, 0.219303759835192, 0.219308537580622, 0.219305529334513, 0.219404905815325, 0.219403019314926, 0.219302596668474, 0.219333591104669, 0.219339691330575, 0.219138199582819, 0.218808232394892, 0.21862547568137, 0.217813259798987, 0.218071071020893, 0.218126099353004, 0.21801371238704, 0.218217144602222, 0.218186406055183, 0.218160214186533, 0.217613149482091, 0.217297311719424, 0.216921598836798, 0.216886531831567, 0.216869443189717, 0.216895243273095, 0.216992451407759, 0.216779869099981, 0.216715362406786, 0.216782476229447, 0.216628059262821, 0.216469933413926, 0.216470605917547, 0.216409392265033, 0.216537300706589, 0.216262240592122, 0.216172533946436, 0.215698974382028, 0.215466640822865, 0.215720328515775, 0.215195583643126, 0.217806277785717, 0.2178311807524, 0.217244068883317, 0.218187732589532, 0.218218958791764, 0.218016932562116, 0.217811629505962, 0.217732987527718, 0.217873250837996, 0.217985226015088, 0.217989357268364, 0.217557116840282, 0.217444425402065, 0.217426023665022, 0.217524570013801, 0.217247146089949, 0.217266721381979, 0.217093020878191, 0.216952587309252, 0.216878350328864, 0.217209585456646, 0.217087040447174, 0.217009465770626, 0.216840267866476, 0.216828987518491, 0.21693827916567, 0.217166553613278, 0.217180207445256, 0.217373695022239, 0.217322541728757, 0.217324637266103, 0.217327550926527, 0.217451974602723, 0.217490605071071, 0.217571815956399, 0.217468213076912, 0.217297079835864, 0.217319940335529, 0.217370081965867, 0.217410758979974, 0.217365347472455, 0.217312297866112, 0.216894972514671, 0.216916971378834, 0.216927929423001, 0.216880915768745, 0.216881319378257, 0.217009238500502, 0.217003165315578, 0.217004748863254, 0.21701650039403, 0.217015054543806, 0.217048421169708, 0.217049418219586, 0.217007912594355, 0.217025915167897, 0.216871925083452, 0.216927497446706, 0.216934230243114, 0.216951557834727, 0.216991958366158, 0.217029362820244, 0.217083290051199, 0.217048390782159, 0.217171159922855, 0.217280374330946, 0.217276026547555, 0.217216744154985, 0.217273660122334, 0.217276041496074, 0.217220793243445, 0.217226734383279, 0.217223959703248, 0.217250964478871, 0.217087682311829, 0.217044071461808, 0.217172832136015, 0.216499622360394, 0.21638996008073, 0.216812667802217, 0.216697472780232, 0.216708436238815, 0.216736311300962, 0.216692232493857, 0.216907050812607, 0.217118813214285, 0.217023338083543, 0.217038423787153, 0.217414052331065, 0.217407201483883, 0.217461369006772, 0.217543822171223, 0.217523360383044, 0.217734048158787, 0.217973112513555, 0.217985432846306, 0.217987739289465, 0.217937914607489, 0.217884729648709, 0.217916880143048, 0.217806347927511, 0.217731842768728, 0.217808164646269, 0.217852077037923, 0.217892146727977, 0.217936872820116, 0.217950293184636, 0.217932486010376, 0.217919910834581, 0.217568927742625, 0.217709881646753, 0.217599751053336, 0.217611475281775, 
0.217600923654268, 0.217642544277135, 0.217475885262979, 0.217480569755149, 0.217530844080224, 0.217580856021759, 0.217618818578885, 0.217601266054404, 0.217463078336142, 0.21745321406011, 0.217566465029886, 0.21755916928927, 0.217551187576845, 0.217637555979833, 0.217651980019569, 0.217850758706321, 0.21783465919771, 0.217825968389065, 0.217807458511111, 0.217814751827357, 0.217783507963404, 0.217791494478799, 0.217785839303163, 0.217835058517766, 0.21786632869287, 0.217858017613214, 0.217872029949717, 0.217867798573574, 0.217873846406077, 0.217844637803948, 0.217859763062461, 0.217855605999771, 0.217882113955261, 0.217891974770414, 0.217882163641107, 0.217880237683436, 0.217894939213953, 0.217949684259951, 0.217959319929622, 0.21797285377485, 0.218041172186086, 0.218111517060791, 0.218149654590506, 0.218139356733247, 0.218196329620811, 0.218188890309925, 0.218201662940889, 0.218245731308144, 0.21827276107351, 0.218258473021243, 0.218322741884883, 0.218310529948176, 0.218313959458195, 0.218313754439997, 0.218306842504346, 0.218300726378134, 0.218313622595547, 0.21842865600127, 0.218405505443825, 0.218393168047389, 0.218410519856679, 0.218210003107985, 0.21813897530049, 0.21791514127928, 0.217871073814684, 0.217863581458704, 0.217845073659016, 0.217882752664317, 0.217894890637032, 0.217909393512176, 0.217904226593551, 0.217911995780017, 0.217985467653295, 0.218051390386744, 0.218107202619451, 0.218115624813903, 0.21811247637043, 0.218130738352036, 0.218082739092671, 0.218101190004053, 0.218055966519318, 0.218173787132293, 0.218163587654213, 0.218106790838072, 0.218151024789873, 0.218174863745909, 0.218464617823987, 0.218408325949648, 0.218333169984797, 0.218341954587723, 0.218459133444117, 0.218497432127628, 
0.218529285621723, 0.218466066087278, 0.218450443639925, 0.218612312950178, 0.218625551236129, 0.21856979358855, 0.218591553801471, 0.218586822585285, 0.218495201782765, 0.218475674882667, 0.218443134178296, 0.217964977512337, 0.217994106593569, 0.217268169016181, 0.217065818677276, 0.217062871205704, 0.217049602028031, 0.217089226618341, 0.217096201916788, 0.217260166177692, 0.21724823755094, 0.217124090777664, 0.217074650739589, 0.216901677906322, 0.216843134095403, 0.216926131814381, 0.216921395172546, 0.216886595101649, 0.216911419925289, 0.21687066690479, 0.216846773984469, 0.216854956667436, 0.216829805334953, 0.216780090203657, 0.216574863507063, 0.216483471959826, 0.216392133097005, 0.21643230103607, 0.216378918436113, 0.216369359131274, 0.216293516942139, 0.216392681904286, 0.216374472108616, 0.216436234824582, 0.216429065193724, 0.215977538253493, 0.21606072690004, 0.2160041111478, 0.215986089851722, 0.215887585357417, 0.215796267262591, 0.21574942206974, 0.215912495000918, 0.215876477977751, 0.215900468700505, 0.215931783785417, 0.216320452068163, 0.216302712674563, 0.216352012767308, 0.216540000404463, 0.216344243248879, 0.216100530101306, 0.216119038067417, 0.216189861095482, 0.216317879855449, 0.2162757385979, 0.216236768244242, 0.216243919447051, 0.21627444599059, 0.216036331100952, 0.215688201108565, 0.21578017312545, 0.215800674490674, 0.215829697447784, 0.215886276467156, 0.215906263063857, 0.215921470375255, 0.215937155987692, 0.216121572990104, 0.216119325344087, 0.216163959784774, 0.216021607022737, 0.21589927040904, 0.215917573768703, 0.215836900089163, 0.215830835442458, 0.215619556258814, 0.216031647923587, 0.216308694959281, 0.216274277309817, 0.215828139436584, 0.216567015269705, 0.216513905374993, 0.216325896030464, 0.216332994414471, 0.216399722002687, 0.216916951319404, 0.216902022632257, 0.216812500295495, 0.216857229130599, 0.216789861197808, 0.216728853597145, 0.216729535564657, 0.216693707328252, 0.216705663416225, 0.217465940232614, 0.217369186877776, 0.217489820869247, 
0.217609835942369, 0.217577298840701, 0.217659257692806, 0.217945467359325, 0.217949225914142, 0.217996570823813, 0.218014569201486, 0.217813679728475, 0.217749088150262, 0.217764456918024, 0.217790086541941, 0.217639462521519, 0.217531361828044, 0.217532229263885, 0.217568213817858, 0.217665629436662, 0.217357423107243, 0.217368890936016, 0.217286425636845, 0.216983492990029, 
0.216906909423506, 0.216844270456614, 0.217131743735174, 0.217118003085994, 0.217054356297036, 0.216953656908279, 0.216847663612646, 0.216840382538953, 0.216634208189167, 0.217782319457363, 0.217647329575814, 0.21763286498373, 0.217701678671705, 0.217686527700144, 0.218395347933348, 0.218393945274687, 0.218347058273995, 0.218981043910263, 0.218995332899675, 0.219161186211194, 0.219229760291369, 0.219290834675094, 0.219269333866627, 0.219335781789526, 0.219331470868454, 0.219263854889853, 0.219187305253529, 0.21861049643452, 0.218635279435254, 0.218733799741655, 0.218720558757573, 0.218846320683796, 0.218943126369255, 0.218869896312965, 0.219026774447187, 0.219019790017436, 0.219101416310773, 0.218748489009591, 0.218754432178698, 0.218746308795306, 0.21877238898308, 0.218626306241118, 0.218714632122058, 0.218908892611659, 0.218909215693087, 0.218931943105087, 0.218947517313813, 0.218673537058913, 0.218680004881372, 0.219514083717882, 0.219490205712695, 0.218710936475516, 0.218896188657438, 0.218927355858217, 0.219305597184599, 0.219468848782022, 0.219523566898569, 0.219584306556309, 0.219765769851883, 0.219612335286181, 0.219483383834189, 0.219333361436551, 0.219394870428097, 0.219340704596692, 0.219379633002215, 0.219400947654446, 0.219457599652927, 0.219493010839121, 0.219714351602803, 0.219720319777292, 0.219692666899645, 0.21974547323626, 0.219863847195214, 0.220250276053365, 0.220267997707088, 0.220399813566856, 0.220450421825232, 0.22045982654679, 0.221044547253648, 0.221029841297845, 0.221025983876479, 0.221028759537789, 0.22102677124964, 0.221354382991021, 0.221344030026005, 0.221411463707881, 0.221410383904904, 0.221351240150523, 0.22134741522313, 0.221307182199527, 0.221336454002443, 0.221530466136706, 0.221409770913285, 0.221418835637027, 0.221428150074142, 0.22140811916689, 0.221490341815545, 0.221538370438024, 0.221535631176995, 0.221539261584083, 0.221529826035606, 0.221517876991509, 0.221439329491863, 0.221527433748103, 0.221363306676618, 0.222152029773528, 0.222133790083725, 0.222119240276656, 0.222571292308224, 0.222617173715808, 0.222594801448108, 0.222543958702342, 0.222378977295096, 0.222618278839072, 0.222569667092097, 0.222577039759024, 0.222553623949827, 0.222265459019078, 0.221898293857706, 0.221987404868731, 0.222029300543936, 0.222012113749821, 0.221802188211151, 0.221784962074043, 0.220117545918147, 0.220170692505279, 0.220182746530293, 0.220138863190637, 0.22019792190325, 0.220123650155717, 0.220124010003244, 0.220105742126731, 
0.220035648875497, 0.220033022967086, 0.219864818105582, 0.219927626221313, 0.219725739782521, 0.219980247408379, 0.219944444246673, 0.219994716128738, 0.219648350515785, 0.220625606609322, 0.220912135065688, 0.220930714464572, 0.220695988989445, 0.220964998108486, 0.221102599732216, 0.221092431487128, 0.221069132070843, 0.221232559883904, 0.221283483924733, 0.221321783246303, 0.221261060985152, 0.221208586050713, 0.221204169326017, 0.221204605642686, 0.221125158236573, 0.221111684931975, 0.22113947042425, 0.221260192181588, 0.221345286073646, 0.221545108117072, 0.221379226715751, 0.221456396871684, 0.221386892051213, 0.221375125543904, 0.22137743182452, 0.221457918362917, 0.22146931187736, 0.222467461639641, 0.222307471429918, 0.22216320489858, 0.222406990929612, 0.222440451237491, 0.222435855511242, 0.222375166736779, 0.222347057192669, 0.222366250557855, 0.222555795670714, 0.222253405047739, 0.222109623091949, 0.221838463384401, 0.221741425149466, 0.221722973894889, 0.221684712025732, 0.221709488940705, 0.221682257931999, 0.221078385509961, 0.220248719078039, 0.220075429727283, 0.220030574040273, 0.219380152052451, 0.21921760987394, 0.219040552382267, 0.219068820554604, 0.21845531346404, 0.218468390294094, 0.218677698001889, 0.218751809055679, 0.218888305177651, 0.218896819047292, 0.219129366665515, 0.219294467929545, 0.219256343425503, 0.219255558048601, 0.219033469029315, 0.21960672216628, 0.219679935694736, 0.219655115056687, 0.219722801204956, 0.219660639999841, 0.219814632291836, 0.219575297131235, 0.219542852572835, 0.219604535115636, 0.219649146443274, 0.219661477117102, 0.219660508505485, 0.219578495045341, 0.219811731302366, 0.219799074857979, 0.219822327964996, 0.219812096776713, 0.219738206538913, 0.219741417968515, 0.219756007251922, 0.220445947457748, 0.220449236614984, 0.22045382706585, 0.220699626586048, 0.220891076077203, 0.220647002967448, 0.220966590464419, 0.221076858099077, 0.221199588991738, 0.221020391194367, 0.220998886431973, 0.220729177241402, 0.220683999425887, 0.220438230650005, 0.220391035920173, 0.220384489832452, 0.220293648086094, 0.220476337692587, 0.220521874607574, 0.220586632548807, 0.220475047542727, 0.22058093679145, 0.220588596846972, 0.220536742956465, 0.220529116998138, 0.22053664648333, 0.220604250898976, 0.220639690013959, 0.220612202949496, 0.220675995370244, 0.220809024460941, 0.220964425976945, 0.221008683870512, 0.220919701062125, 0.22089294173481, 0.220949176616655, 0.220940912550212, 0.220909643723448, 0.220873096503, 0.220922002533922, 0.220997825168621, 0.22100180264718, 0.221067453249175, 0.22102388951016, 0.221011403700056, 0.220988821510404, 0.221028340929608, 0.220965946576269, 0.220973172201268, 0.221027534158611, 0.221016672103757, 0.221019958215058, 0.221104130865256, 0.221216510402052, 0.221207730873675, 0.221230263105236, 0.221521359877835, 0.221510182239683, 0.221269292929683, 0.221280033477113, 0.221348591454748, 0.221390706287107, 0.22130635351869, 0.221319587689095, 0.221332312207507, 0.221558631098318, 0.221463042511544, 0.221555138764276, 0.221442686461275, 0.221360824631536, 0.221534930659912, 0.221543822102166, 0.221651859072522, 0.22170380924255, 0.221679007224324, 0.221767849533625, 0.221738380580738, 0.221710234314812, 0.221730355088888, 0.221727608130189, 0.221781404204836, 0.221787112540176, 0.221760261940851, 0.22175715357493, 0.221739660101365, 0.221774561834118, 0.221790143738379, 0.22178860739854, 0.221783799474442, 0.221799957941379, 0.2217704727755, 0.221795764497748, 0.221709263808821, 0.221619719206199, 0.221836449438405, 0.221779992682008, 0.221631744840436, 0.221674473942542, 0.221687766166408, 0.222061508274093, 0.222136253445234, 0.222255310462222
), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), .CLASS = structure("double", class = "CLASS"), formattable = structure(list(formatter = "formatC", format = structure(list(format = "f", digits = 2), .Names = c("format", "digits")), preproc = "percent_preproc", postproc = "percent_postproc"), .Names = c("formatter", "format", "preproc", "postproc")), index = structure(c(1495597500, 1495598400, 
1495599300, 1495600200, 1495601100, 1495602000, 1495602900, 1495603800, 1495604700, 1495605600, 1495606500, 1495607400, 1495608300, 1495609200, 1495610100, 1495611000, 1495611900, 1495612800, 1495613700, 1495614600, 1495615500, 1495616400, 1495617300, 1495618200, 1495619100, 1495620000, 1495620900, 1495621800, 1495622700, 1495623600, 1495624500, 1495625400, 1495626300, 1495627200, 1495628100, 1495629000, 1495629900, 1495630800, 1495631700, 1495632600, 1495633500, 1495634400, 1495635300, 1495636200, 1495637100, 1495638000, 1495638900, 1495639800, 1495640700, 1495641600, 1495642500, 1495643400, 1495644300, 1495645200, 1495646100, 1495647000, 1495647900, 1495648800, 1495649700, 1495650600, 1495651500, 1495652400, 1495653300, 1495654200, 1495655100, 1495656000, 1495657800, 1495658700, 1495663200, 1495664100, 1495665000, 1495665900, 1495666800, 1495667700, 1495668600, 1495669500, 1495670400, 1495671300, 1495672200, 1495673100, 1495674000, 1495674900, 1495675800, 1495676700, 1495677600, 1495678500, 1495679400, 1495680300, 1495681200, 1495682100, 1495683000, 1495683900, 1495684800, 1495685700, 1495686600, 1495687500, 1495688400, 1495689300, 1495690200, 1495691100, 1495692000, 1495692900, 1495693800, 1495694700, 1495695600, 1495696500, 1495697400, 1495698300, 1495699200, 1495700100, 1495701000, 1495701900, 1495702800, 1495703700, 1495704600, 1495705500, 1495706400, 1495707300, 1495708200, 1495709100, 1495710000, 1495710900, 1495711800, 1495712700, 1495713600, 1495714500, 1495715400, 1495716300, 
1495717200, 1495718100, 1495719000, 1495719900, 1495720800, 1495721700, 1495722600, 1495723500, 1495724400, 1495725300, 1495726200, 1495727100, 1495728000, 1495728900, 1495729800, 1495730700, 1495731600, 1495732500, 1495733400, 1495734300, 1495735200, 1495736100, 1495737000, 1495737900, 1495738800, 1495739700, 1495740600, 1495741500, 1495742400, 1495744200, 1495745100, 1495749600, 1495750500, 1495751400, 1495752300, 1495753200, 1495754100, 1495755000, 1495755900, 1495756800, 1495757700, 1495758600, 1495759500, 1495760400, 1495761300, 1495762200, 1495763100, 1495764000, 1495764900, 1495765800, 1495766700, 1495767600, 1495768500, 1495769400, 1495770300, 1495771200, 1495772100, 1495773000, 1495773900, 1495774800, 1495775700, 1495776600, 1495777500, 1495778400, 1495779300, 1495780200, 1495781100, 1495782000, 1495782900, 1495783800, 1495784700, 1495785600, 1495786500, 1495787400, 1495788300, 1495789200, 1495790100, 1495791000, 1495791900, 1495792800, 1495793700, 1495794600, 1495795500, 1495796400, 1495797300, 1495798200, 1495799100, 1495800000, 1495800900, 1495801800, 1495802700, 1495803600, 1495804500, 1495805400, 1495806300, 1495807200, 1495808100, 1495809000, 1495809900, 1495810800, 1495811700, 1495812600, 1495813500, 1495814400, 1495815300, 1495816200, 1495817100, 1495818000, 1495818900, 1495819800, 1495820700, 1495821600, 1495822500, 1495823400, 1495824300, 1495825200, 1495826100, 1495827000, 1495827900, 1495828800, 1495830600, 1495831500, 1496008800, 1496009700, 1496010600, 1496011500, 1496012400, 1496013300, 1496014200, 1496015100, 1496016000, 1496016900, 1496017800, 1496018700, 1496019600, 1496020500, 1496021400, 1496022300, 1496023200, 1496024100, 1496025000, 1496025900, 1496026800, 1496027700, 1496028600, 1496029500, 1496030400, 1496031300, 1496032200, 1496033100, 1496034000, 1496034900, 1496035800, 1496036700, 1496037600, 1496038500, 1496039400, 1496040300, 1496041200, 1496042100, 1496043000, 1496043900, 1496044800, 1496045700, 1496046600, 1496047500, 1496048400, 1496049300, 1496050200, 1496051100, 1496052000, 1496052900, 1496053800, 1496054700, 1496055600, 1496056500, 1496057400, 1496058300, 1496059200, 1496060100, 1496061000, 1496061900, 1496062800, 1496063700, 1496064600, 1496065500, 1496066400, 1496067300, 1496068200, 1496069100, 1496070000, 1496070900, 1496071800, 1496072700, 1496073600, 1496074500, 1496075400, 1496076300, 1496095200, 1496096100, 1496097000, 1496097900, 1496098800, 1496099700, 1496100600, 1496101500, 1496102400, 1496103300, 1496104200, 1496105100, 1496106000, 1496106900, 1496107800, 1496108700, 1496109600, 1496110500, 1496111400, 1496112300, 1496113200, 1496114100, 1496115000, 1496115900, 1496116800, 1496117700, 1496118600, 1496119500, 1496120400, 1496121300, 1496122200, 1496123100, 1496124000, 1496124900, 1496125800, 1496126700, 1496127600, 1496128500, 1496129400, 1496130300, 1496131200, 1496132100, 1496133000, 1496133900, 1496134800, 1496135700, 1496136600, 1496137500, 1496138400, 1496139300, 1496140200, 1496141100, 1496142000, 1496142900, 1496143800, 1496144700, 1496145600, 1496146500, 1496147400, 1496148300, 1496149200, 1496150100, 1496151000, 1496151900, 1496152800, 1496153700, 1496154600, 1496155500, 1496156400, 1496157300, 1496158200, 1496159100, 
1496160000, 1496160900, 1496161800, 1496162700, 1496163600, 1496164500, 1496165400, 1496166300, 1496167200, 1496168100, 1496169000, 1496169900, 1496170800, 1496171700, 1496172600, 1496173500, 1496174400, 1496176200, 1496177100, 1496181600, 1496182500, 1496183400, 1496184300, 1496185200, 1496186100, 1496187000, 1496187900, 1496188800, 1496189700, 1496190600, 1496191500, 1496192400, 1496193300, 1496194200, 1496195100, 1496196000, 1496196900, 1496197800, 1496198700, 1496199600, 1496200500, 1496201400, 1496202300, 1496203200, 1496204100, 1496205000, 1496205900, 1496206800, 1496207700, 1496208600, 1496209500, 1496210400, 1496211300, 1496212200, 1496213100, 1496214000, 1496214900, 1496215800, 1496216700, 1496217600, 1496218500, 1496219400, 1496220300, 1496221200, 1496222100, 1496223000, 1496223900, 1496224800, 1496225700, 1496226600, 1496227500, 1496228400, 1496229300, 1496230200, 1496231100, 1496232000, 1496232900, 1496233800, 1496234700, 1496235600, 1496236500, 1496237400, 1496238300, 1496239200, 1496240100, 1496241000, 1496241900, 1496242800, 1496243700, 1496244600, 1496245500, 1496246400, 1496247300, 1496248200, 1496249100, 1496250000, 1496250900, 1496251800, 1496252700, 1496253600, 1496254500, 1496255400, 1496256300, 1496257200, 1496258100, 1496259000, 1496259900, 1496260800, 1496262600, 1496263500, 1496268000, 1496268900, 1496269800, 1496270700, 1496271600, 1496272500, 1496273400, 1496274300, 1496275200, 1496276100, 1496277000, 1496277900, 1496278800, 1496279700, 1496280600, 1496281500, 1496282400, 1496283300, 1496284200, 1496285100, 1496286000, 1496286900, 1496287800, 1496288700, 1496289600, 1496290500, 1496291400, 1496292300, 1496293200, 1496294100, 1496295000, 1496295900, 1496296800, 1496297700, 1496298600, 1496299500, 1496300400, 1496301300, 1496302200, 1496303100, 1496304000, 1496304900, 1496305800, 1496306700, 1496307600, 1496308500, 1496309400, 1496310300, 1496311200, 1496312100, 1496313000, 1496313900, 1496314800, 1496315700, 1496316600, 1496317500, 1496318400, 1496319300, 1496320200, 1496321100, 1496322000, 1496322900, 1496323800, 1496324700, 1496325600, 1496326500, 1496327400, 1496328300, 1496329200, 1496330100, 1496331000, 1496331900, 1496332800, 1496333700, 1496334600, 1496335500, 1496336400, 1496337300, 1496338200, 1496339100, 1496340000, 1496340900, 1496341800, 1496342700, 1496343600, 1496344500, 1496345400, 1496346300, 1496347200, 1496349000, 1496349900, 1496354400, 1496355300, 1496356200, 1496357100, 1496358000, 1496358900, 1496359800, 1496360700, 1496361600, 1496362500, 1496363400, 1496364300, 1496365200, 1496366100, 1496367000, 1496367900, 1496368800, 1496369700, 1496370600, 1496371500, 1496372400, 1496373300, 1496374200, 1496375100, 1496376000, 1496376900, 1496377800, 1496378700, 1496379600, 1496380500, 1496381400, 1496382300, 1496383200, 1496384100, 1496385000, 1496385900, 1496386800, 1496387700, 1496388600, 1496389500, 1496390400, 1496391300, 1496392200, 1496393100, 1496394000, 1496394900, 1496395800, 1496396700, 1496397600, 1496398500, 1496399400, 1496400300, 1496401200, 1496402100, 1496403000, 1496403900, 1496404800, 1496405700, 1496406600, 1496407500, 1496408400, 1496409300, 1496410200, 1496411100, 1496412000, 1496412900, 1496413800, 1496414700, 1496415600, 1496416500, 1496417400, 1496418300, 1496419200, 1496420100, 1496421000, 1496421900, 1496422800, 1496423700, 1496424600, 1496425500, 1496426400, 
1496427300, 1496428200, 1496429100, 1496430000, 1496430900, 1496431800, 1496432700, 1496433600, 1496435400, 1496436300, 1496617200, 1496618100, 1496619000, 1496619900, 1496620800, 1496621700, 1496622600, 1496623500, 1496624400, 1496625300, 1496626200, 1496627100, 1496628000, 1496628900, 1496629800, 1496630700, 1496631600, 1496632500, 1496633400, 1496634300, 1496635200, 1496636100, 1496637000, 1496637900, 1496638800, 1496639700, 1496640600, 1496641500, 1496642400, 1496643300, 1496644200, 1496645100, 1496646000, 1496646900, 1496647800, 1496648700, 1496649600, 1496650500, 1496651400, 1496652300, 1496653200, 1496654100, 1496655000, 1496655900, 1496656800, 1496657700, 1496658600, 1496659500, 1496660400, 1496661300, 1496662200, 1496663100, 1496664000, 1496664900, 1496665800, 1496666700, 1496667600, 1496668500, 1496669400, 1496670300, 1496671200, 1496672100, 1496673000, 1496673900, 1496674800, 1496675700, 1496676600, 1496677500, 1496678400, 1496679300, 1496680200, 1496681100, 1496682000, 1496682900, 1496683800, 1496684700, 1496685600, 1496686500, 1496687400, 1496688300, 1496689200, 1496690100, 1496691000, 1496691900, 1496692800, 1496694600, 1496695500, 1496700000, 1496700900, 1496701800, 1496702700, 1496703600, 1496704500, 1496705400, 1496706300, 1496707200, 1496708100, 1496709000, 1496709900, 1496710800, 1496711700, 1496712600, 1496713500, 1496714400, 1496715300, 1496716200, 1496717100, 1496718000, 1496718900), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(799L, 1L))

#Plotting with condition to remove x-axis, NOT WORKING
plot(XTS2, xaxt ="n")
```

Screenshot showing the unwanted x-axis:
[image]

Comment: hmmm, from your code I got a plot without `x-axis`

Comment: Thanks. I added a screenshot for illustration purposes. Are you sure you did not see the x-axis? It can be visually misleading as its only showing labels on the edges. Two labels on the edges is nothing, but when applied to a large database I have those labels all over the place, obstructing a second superimposed axis with different labels.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your plot on my machine. I am getting a plot with frame plot, so I can't see the `x-axis`

Comment: Not reproducible over here either.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I just reproduced it on a different computer, copying/pasting the code from the question as is (from scratch). The x-axis presence can be appreciated on the chart's edges, where it reads "Oct 22 8:45" and "Oct 24 12:15".

Comment: So the example is certainly reproducible - as said it may be visually misleading  because the presence of the unwanted x-axis can only be appreciated on the right/left edges. I am adding a second example where it can be appreciate all along the x-axis (rather than only on the edges). This 2nd example is a larger XTS object. The larger the object, the more observations present in the middle of the x-axis.

Comment: Ran into a character limit, so simply replaced 1st example with 2nd example.

Comment: This is a bug, and has been [reported as such](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/196).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165239/remove-y-axis-label-from-plot-of-an-xts-object?rq=1). Solution:

`plot.zoo(XTS2, xaxt ='n')`

i.e. need to use `plot.zoo` rather than `plot` given that it is an XTS object.

Comment: I got a perfectly fine plot just using `plot()`. What versions of xts and zoo are you using? It could be your version is out-of-date. I'm using xts_0.9-7   and zoo_1.7-14.

Comment: Interesting. Using xts_0.10-0 / zoo_1.8-0 on R version 3.2.4. Tested it on 2 computers with same versions installed.